# Add table to powerpoint slide using Open XML

Tags: powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I got the code for the Table in the powerpoint using the code generator, but I am not able to add the table to an existing powerpoint document.

I tried adding another table to the intended slide and doing the following:

```
Table table = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Table>().First();
table.RemoveAllChildren();
Table createdTable = CreateTable();

foreach (OpenXmlElement childElement in createdTable.ChildElements)
{
    table.AppendChild(childElement.CloneNode(true));
}
```

But that didn't work.

I am out of ideas on this issue.
My original target is to add a table with dynamic number of columns and fixed number of row to my presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been very long since this question is posted, but just in case if some one needs a working code to create table in pptx.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ANF.Slides.TestEngine
{
class Program
{
    static int index = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing Presentation");
        PopulateData();
       // GeneratedClass cls=new GeneratedClass();
        //cls.CreatePackage(@"E:\output.pptx");
        Console.WriteLine("Completed Presentation");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PopulateData()
    {
        var overflow = false;
        const int pageBorder = 3000000;
        var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
        var products = db.Products;//.Take(5);
        const string outputFile = @"E:\openxml\output.pptx";
        File.Copy(@"E:\OpenXml\Template.pptx", outputFile, true);

        using (var myPres = PresentationDocument.Open(outputFile, true))
        {
            var presPart = myPres.PresentationPart;
            var slideIdList = presPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;

            var list = slideIdList.ChildElements
                        .Cast<SlideId>()
                        .Select(x => presPart.GetPartById(x.RelationshipId))
                        .Cast<SlidePart>();


            var tableSlidePart = (SlidePart)list.Last();
            var current = tableSlidePart;
            long totalHeight = 0;
            foreach (var product in products)
            {

                if (overflow)
                {
                    var newTablePart = CloneSlidePart(presPart, tableSlidePart);
                    current = newTablePart;
                    overflow = false;
                    totalHeight = 0;
                }




                var tbl = current.Slide.Descendants<A.Table>().First();
                var tr = new A.TableRow();
                tr.Height = 200000;
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.Name));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.ProductNumber));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.Size));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(String.Format("{0:00}", product.ListPrice)));
                tr.Append(CreateTextCell(product.SellStartDate.ToShortDateString()));
                tbl.Append(tr);


                totalHeight += tr.Height;


              if (totalHeight > pageBorder)
                    overflow = true;
            }
        }
    }


    static SlidePart CloneSlidePart(PresentationPart presentationPart, SlidePart slideTemplate)
    {
        //Create a new slide part in the presentation 
        SlidePart newSlidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>("newSlide" + index);
        index++;
        //Add the slide template content into the new slide 
        newSlidePart.FeedData(slideTemplate.GetStream(FileMode.Open));
        //make sure the new slide references the proper slide layout 
        newSlidePart.AddPart(slideTemplate.SlideLayoutPart);
        //Get the list of slide ids 
        SlideIdList slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
        //Figure out where to add the next slide (find max slide) 
        uint maxSlideId = 1;
        SlideId prevSlideId = null;
        foreach (SlideId slideId in slideIdList.ChildElements)
        {
            if (slideId.Id > maxSlideId)
            {
                maxSlideId = slideId.Id;
                prevSlideId = slideId;
            }
        }
        maxSlideId++;
        //Add new slide at the end of the deck 
        SlideId newSlideId = slideIdList.InsertAfter(new SlideId(), prevSlideId);
        //Make sure id and relid is set appropriately 
        newSlideId.Id = maxSlideId;
        newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(newSlidePart);
        return newSlidePart;
    }


    private static A.TableCell CreateTextCell(string text)
    {
        var textCol = new string[2];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            if (text.Length > 25)
            {
                textCol[0] = text.Substring(0, 25);
                textCol[1] = text.Substring(26);
            }
            else
            {
                textCol[0] = text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textCol[0] = string.Empty;
        }


        A.TableCell tableCell3 = new A.TableCell();

        A.TextBody textBody3 = new A.TextBody();
        A.BodyProperties bodyProperties3 = new A.BodyProperties();
        A.ListStyle listStyle3 = new A.ListStyle();

        textBody3.Append(bodyProperties3);
        textBody3.Append(listStyle3);


        var nonNull = textCol.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).ToList();

        foreach (var textVal in nonNull)
        {
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textVal))
            //{
            A.Paragraph paragraph3 = new A.Paragraph();
            A.Run run2 = new A.Run();
            A.RunProperties runProperties2 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };
            A.Text text2 = new A.Text();
            text2.Text = textVal;
            run2.Append(runProperties2);
            run2.Append(text2);
            paragraph3.Append(run2);
            textBody3.Append(paragraph3);
            //}
        }

        A.TableCellProperties tableCellProperties3 = new A.TableCellProperties();
        tableCell3.Append(textBody3);
        tableCell3.Append(tableCellProperties3);



        //var tc = new A.TableCell(
        //                    new A.TextBody(
        //                        new A.BodyProperties(),
        //                    new A.Paragraph(
        //                        new A.Run(
        //                            new A.Text(text)))),
        //                    new A.TableCellProperties());

        //return tc;
       return tableCell3;
    }
}
}
```